# Find the minimum values of x, y, and z

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If:

\begin{aligned}
\ {n} & = \ 2x ^2 \\
\ {n} & = \ 3y^3 \\
\ {n} & = \ 5z^5 \\
\end{aligned}

Find the minimum value for $x, y,$ and $z$.

Note: $n$ is the minimum value you can get by solving the set of equations.

Comment: What is $n$? ${}{}$

Comment: lowest in what sense?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are real numbers?

Comment: Yes x,y,z are real numbers

Comment: How do you mean "lowest for $x,y,z$
"--are they to be minimized separately? simultaneously?

Comment: I think $x,y,z,n$ are positive integers (otherwise $0$ is the (not very interesting) solution)

Comment: Can $x,y,z$ be *any* real numbers, or should they be integers? If integers, should they be positive?

Comment: I think he wants to minimize $n$.

Comment: @CameronBuie:  The question doesn't make sense unless $x,y,z$ are positive integers.  Otherwise we can take $n=0$ or for positive reals $n$ can be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that $n$ is a positive **integer**, as are $x$, $y$, and $z$. Then $n$ must be divisible by the primes $2$, $3$, and $5$. To minimize $n$, we allow no other primes.

Let $n=2^a3^b5^c$.  Since $n=2x^2$, $a$ must be odd, and $b$ and $c$ even.  This is because in the prime power factorization of a perfect square, each prime must occur to an even power.

Since $n=3y^3$, $a$ must be divisible by $3$, and $b-1$ must be divisible by $3$, and $c$ must be divisible by $3$.  This is because in the prime power factorization of a perfect cube, each prime must occur to a power divisible by $3$.

Since $n=5z^5$, $a$ must be divisible by $5$, and $b$ must be divisible by $5$, and $c-1$ must be divisible by $5$.

Now we look for the smallest non-negative integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy our conditions.

Start with $a$. We must have $a$ odd, $a$ divisible by $3$ and by $5$. It is clear that the cheapest $a$ is $15$.

We want $b$ to be even, and a multiple of $5$, and we want $b-1$ to be divisible by $3$. So $b$ is a multiple of $10$. Easily, $b=10$ satisfies the additional condition $b-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Do something similar to find the cheapest $c$.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP requires $x,y,z$ to be integers.

Comment: Should have $n=5z^5$. Good answer!

Comment: Well since it was an Olympiad problem they are supposed to be integers.